# Removing Rows Based on Column Value in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a simple table in R named `Tag_Count`:

```
Tag 1    freq
Cookies   1
Cakes     2
Burritos  5
```

I want to remove all rows where freq value is less than 3. I tried:

```
Tag_Count_2 <- Tag_Count[Tag_Count$freq <= 3,]
Tag_Count_2 <- Tag_Count[freq < 4]
```

But neither worked.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 3. But I used your suggestion and it spit back the table with nothing altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
Tag_Count[!(Tag_Count$freq <= 3),]
```

If this is not a `data.frame`, then

```
Tag_Count[!(Tag_Count[,"freq"] <= 3),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <-  df %>%
     filter(freq >= 3)

print(df1)
      Tag1 freq
1 Burritos    5

data
df <- data.frame(Tag1 = c("Cookies","Cakes","Burritos"),freq = c(1,2,5), stringsAsFactors = F)
```